# Binary search algorithm for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have to search through in a spreadsheet with the first column is a list of emails without @ part. For example

```
aadb.asdf
asdfsd.asdf
asdfsad.asdfsdf
asdfsdf.asdfsdf
```

Below is my code for binary search:

```
function testSubmit() {


  var email = "aadb.asdf";
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID");
  var sheet = s.getSheets()[0];
  var emailColumn = sheet.getRange(1,1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); 

  var l1 = 0;
  var h1 = Number(sheet.getLastRow()) - 1;  


  while(h1 >= l1) {

    var middle = parseInt((l1 + h1) / 2);
    var item = emailColumn[middle][0].valueOf();
    Logger.log("Binary -> middle : " + middle + " data : " + emailColumn[middle][0]);

    if(item == email) {

    }

    if(item.charAt(0) < email.charAt(0)) {
      l1 = middle + 1;
    }

    if(item.charAt(0)  > email.charAt(0)) {
      h1 = middle - 1;
    }
  }

}
```

But my script get stuck and gives the message is the screenshot below.

[image]

However when I run linear search, it works fine. Is there a problem with my script?

```
 for (var row in emailColumn) {
   for (var col in emailColumn[row]) {
     if(email == emailColumn[row][col]) {
     Logger.log("row : " + row + " col : " + col + " data : " + emailColumn[row][col]);
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Message shown is not an error message. How much do wait? Do you review the script execution transcript? (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting).

Comment: Image attached is not an error message. @Ruben is correct. Other than that, do you receive any other message? What is your expected result? As of now, try to read through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#debugging). It discussed everything including debugging.

Comment: I never said it was an error, but It shouldn't be happening because binary search should take less time than linear. But in my script linear search is quick while binary seems to get stuck at some point. I double check my script for error but I don't see any

Answer (score 0):

Look at your While statement ...it could be that h1 and l1 at a given moment are no longer being changed and thus it gets stuck in the loop.